# Error intercalacion

Tags: sql-server, join

Estoy intentando hacer una JOIN de 2 tablas en bases de datos diferentes en la misma instancia SQL Server que tenian distinto Collation.

He modificado el de la base de datos BOLETUS para que coincida con el de la base de datos FULCRUM y ahora ambas con el mismo valor de Collation 
[image: Collation]

pero cuando la ejecuto me da este error

[image: error]

Sin embargo si pongo el collate antiguo de BOLETUS va bien
[image: collate]

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: Creo recordar que debes hacer el collation a los 3: BD, Tabla y Columna -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531221/3617531.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque cambié el `collation` en las propiedades de la base de datos BOLETUS eso lo cambió en la base de datos y en la tabla OFERTAS pero no en el campo de OFERTAS.CODIGOPRESENTADA y eso lo he tenido que hacer a mano

```
ALTER TABLE "OFERTAS"
ALTER COLUMN "CODIGOPRESENTADA" Char(5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
```

y ahora ya funciona la JOIN en la consulta sin tener que usar collates